# How to create view from its parent's nib using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiview, nib

I thought this question is very simple but after long search without find an answer I'm trying to ask here:

I have a custom view (MyCustomView:UIView) with a .xib file.
To use this class with its nib I add a class function as following

```
class func addCustomViewToView(view: UIView)
{
    let CV = NSBundle(forClass: MyCustomView.self).loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! MyCustomView
    CV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(CV)
}
```

In another place in my application I had to extend my custom view so I created a subClass of my custom view:

```
class MyExtendedCustomClass : MyCustomClass
{ 
    ...
}
```

I tried to override the class function, but I didn't find way to create a sub class item using parent's nib file.

What is the correct way to do this?

thanks

Comment: your addCustomViewToView method is wrong. `loadNibNamed` returns an `NSArray`. You then have to find the view in that array. (I don't have the code handy. You should be able to find it on the net.)  I usually set file's owner to be the parent VC class and then after calling `loadNibNamed` the outlet is connected.

Comment: @DuncanC He probably assigned the view to a property named `PC` in the File Owner. And that's why he's not using the `CV` variable.

Comment: thanks Duncan C, I fixed it, just typo ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite a long time past from I asked the question, I'll add my solution hope it will help to someone.

The main issue was that while I called the function

```
addCustomViewToView(view: UIView)
```

in the subCustomView it created the view as the superCustomView class due to the line:

```
let CV = NSBundle...loadNibNamed(...).first as! MyCustomView
```

so...

Firstly, the way I init my CustomView:

```
var view:UIViwe!

override public init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}

private func commonInit()
{
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: myBundle)
    self.view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    self.view.frame = self.bounds
    self.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
    //here you can add things to your view....
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}

override public class func layerClass() -> AnyClass
{
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}
```

Now I can initiate this class from the code using the

```
init(frame: CGRect)
```

and from storyboard by create view and define it's class to be my CustomView in that case the next init will be called:

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

After that, in the inherited View I shouldn't do nothing, it's "init" will call the "super.init" from the CustomView class and will init the nib file with no problems.